# How do I convert a vector of strings to a vector of integers in a functional way?

Tags: vector, functional-programming, rust

I'm trying to convert `Vec<&str>` to `Vec<u16>` but I can't figure out a functional way to do it.

```
let foo: &str = "1,2,3"; // Parsing a string here
let bar: Vec<&str> = foo.split(",").collect(); // Bar is a nice vector of &str's
```

I need to get `bar` into a `Vec<u16>`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's an iterator adapter [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map)! You'd use it like this:

```
let bar: Vec<u16> = foo.split(",").map(|x| x.parse::<u16>().unwrap()).collect();
```

[`parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) is a library function that relies on the trait [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html), and it can return an error, so we need to `unwrap()` the error type. (This is a good idea for a short example, but in real code, you will want to handle the error properly - if you have a value that's not a `u16` there, your program will just crash).

`map` takes a closure that takes it's parameter by value and then returns the iterator obtained by *lazily* applying that function. You're [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect)ing all of the values here, but if you only [`take(5)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take) of them, you would only parse 5 of the strings.

Answer (score 10):

You haven't fully specified your problem. Specifically, what should happen when one of the strings *cannot* be parsed into a number? When you parse a number from a string using [`parse`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse), it can fail. That is why the function returns a `Result`:

```
fn parse<F>(&self) -> Result<F, F::Err>
where
    F: FromStr,
```

Here's a solution that takes the vector, gets an iterator with [`iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter), changes each item using [`map`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) and ultimately returns a `Result` using [`collect`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect). If the parsing was a success, you get an `Ok`. If *any* failed, you get an `Err`:

```
fn main() {
    let input = "1,2,3";
    let strings: Vec<_> = input.split(",").collect();

    let numbers: Result<Vec<u16>, _> = strings.iter().map(|x| x.parse()).collect();

    println!("{:?}", numbers);
}
```

Or you could remove failed conversions by filtering out `Err` values with [`flat_map`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map):

```
fn main() {
    let input = "1,2,3";
    let strings: Vec<_> = input.split(",").collect();

    let numbers: Vec<u16> = strings.iter().flat_map(|x| x.parse()).collect();

    println!("{:?}", numbers);
}
```

Of course, it's a *bit* silly to convert the string into a vector of strings and then convert it again to a vector of integers. If you actually have a comma-separated string and want numbers, do it in one go:

```
fn main() {
    let input = "1,2,3";

    let numbers: Result<Vec<u16>, _> = input.split(",").map(|x| x.parse()).collect();

    println!("{:?}", numbers);
}
```

See also:

- [Why does `Option` support `IntoIterator`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43285372/155423)

Answer (score 4):

My take as someone not really experienced in Rust yet.

```
fn main() {
    let foo: &str = "1,2,3"; // Parsing a string here
    let bar: Vec<&str> = foo.split(",").collect(); // Bar is a nice vector of &str's

    // here the magic happens
    let baz = bar.iter().map(|x| x.parse::<i64>());

    for x in baz {
        match x {
            Ok(i) => println!("{}", i),
            Err(_) => println!("parse failed"),
        }
    }
}
```

Note that since `parse` returns a `Result`, you have to extract the value from each parsed element. You might want to behave in a different way, e.g. filter only the succeeded results.