# Why does `Option` support `IntoIterator`?

Tags: foreach, rust, option-type

I was trying to iterate over a subsection of a vector of strings, i.e. a subslice of `Vec<String>`. Within each iteration, I wanted to pass the string as a slice to a function.

I didn't notice that `Vec::get` returns an `Option`, and thought I could just directly iterate over the return value:

```rust
fn take_str(s: &str) {
    println!("{}", s);
}

fn main() {
    let str_vec: Vec<String> = ["one", "two", "three", "uno", "dos", "tres"]
        .iter()
        .map(|&s| s.into())
        .collect();
    for s in str_vec.get(0..3) {
        take_str(&s);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:11:18
   |
11 |         take_str(&s); // Type mismatch: found type `&&[std::string::String]`
   |                  ^^ expected `str`, found `&[String]`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&str`
              found reference `&&[String]`
```

I was expecting `s` to be a `String`, but it's actually `&[String]`. This is because my `for` loop is iterating over the `Option` returned by `Vec::get()`.

I also wrote the following code, which demonstrates that the `for` loop is in fact unwrapping an `Option`:

```
let foo = Option::Some(["foo".to_string()]);
for f in foo {
    take_str(&f); // Same error as above, showing `f` is of type `&[String]`
}
```

This is incredibly confusing; I never expected (until I wrote this code and figured out what it's actually doing) that `Option` could be unwrapped by *iterating* over it. Why is that supported? What use case is there for iterating over an `Option`?

Comment: https://github.com/rust-unofficial/patterns/blob/master/idioms/option-iter.md

Comment: @JoshLee That repo looks like a really good thing to read in its entirety! Thank you.

Comment: Updated link from Josh Lee's comment: https://github.com/rust-unofficial/patterns/blob/main/src/idioms/option-iter.md

Answer (score 19):

> What use case is there for iterating over an `Option`?

My favorite reason, in a word, is [`flatten`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten):

```
fn main() {
    let results = [Some(1), None, Some(3), None];
    let sum: i32 = results.into_iter().flatten().sum();
    println!("{}", sum)
}
```

Before Rust 1.29, you can use [`flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map):

```
fn main() {
    let results = vec![Some(1), None, Some(3), None];
    let sum: i32 = results.into_iter().flat_map(|x| x).sum();
    println!("{}", sum)
}
```

`Option` can be thought of as a container that can hold exactly zero or one elements. Compare this to a `Vec`, which can hold zero or many elements. In a large set of ways, an `Option` *is* a container just like a `Vec`!

Implementing `IntoIterator` allows `Option` to participate in a larger share of APIs.

Note that `IntoIterator` is *also* implemented for `Result`, for similar reasons.

> This is incredibly confusing

Yes, it is, which is why Clippy [has a lint for it](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#for_loops_over_fallibles):

```
warning: for loop over `str_vec.get(0..3)`, which is an `Option`. This is more readably written as an `if let` statement
  --> src/main.rs:10:14
   |
10 |     for s in str_vec.get(0..3) {
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(clippy::for_loops_over_fallibles)]` on by default
   = help: consider replacing `for s in str_vec.get(0..3)` with `if let Some(s) = str_vec.get(0..3)`
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#for_loops_over_fallibles
```

This shows that there are ways that an `Option` is *not* like a container to a programmer.

Comment: "`Option` can be thought of as a container that can hold exactly zero or one elements." So...semantically, it's kind of like a `Box` but its owned object is entirely contained instead of heap-allocated? That's...not really the semantics I expected from `Option`, but I guess it makes sense. To be absolutely clear, your `flat_map(|x| x)` is equivalent to something like `map(|x| x.unwrap_or(0))`, correct?

Comment: Why `flat_map()` instead of `filter_map()`? I'd say the latter is more fitting in this situation...

Comment: @KyleStrand the heap-allocation aspect is orthogonal, really. `Vec` uses the heap to have dynamic capacity. There are stack-based collections too, usually with a fixed capacity. I only half-heartedly agree with the `unwrap_or` comparison. In *this* example, yes, they have the same result (due to how addition on integers works), but using `collect` instead of `sum` would show how they are different.

Comment: @KyleStrand: A friendly reminder that `Box` always has an object in Rust, there is no null `Box` :)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt that's a tough question, which has been [discussed at least once before](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/4xkat3/why_filter_map_and_flat_map/?ref=share&ref_source=link). *My* answer is because I like me some functional programming and monads, so I think of `flat_map`. The linked discussion suggests that `filter_map` is less powerful than `flat_map` and thus `filter_map` is the redundant one.

Comment: Hm, you're right that `collect` would be harder to use with `map` instead of `flat_map` in this case. I agree that with @LukasKalbertodt that `filter_map` seems even better, though. What's not "functional" about it? And doesn't it still involve a monad?

Comment: And @MatthieuM.'s point is, I think, the real reason my `Box` comparison doesn't work (I forgot that C++'s `unique_ptr` is actually more like an unsafe `Option<Box>` than mere `Box`).

Comment: @KyleStrand: exactly my point yes; memory layout apart, `Box<T>` only represent a subset of `Option<T>` possible states: it's missing exactly one state, the empty one.

Comment: @KyleStrand Sorry, I don't mean to suggest that one is *more* functional than the other, just that the combined action "flat-map" is the name of something that exists in a functional language like Clojure, while "filter-map" is not, based on my experience. Usually it's composed of separate `filter` and `map` operations. Rust combines the two for ownership reasons.

Comment: Additionally, if you choose to use `filter_map`, you don't get the removal of `Result` for "free"; you have to explicitly convert to an `Option`.