# Rust File examples don't compile

Tags: rust

The Rust [file examples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) don't appear compile with Rust 1.18.0.

For [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=366a4e89c6c880ab467b43da30fb0d94&version=stable&backtrace=0):

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
fn main() {
    let mut file = File::open("foo.txt")?;
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents)?;
    assert_eq!(contents, "Hello, world!");
}
```

Error log:

```
rustc 1.18.0 (03fc9d622 2017-06-06)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(): std::ops::Carrier` is not satisfied
 --> <anon>:4:20
  |
4 |     let mut file = File::open("foo.txt")?;
  |                    ----------------------
  |                    |
  |                    the trait `std::ops::Carrier` is not implemented for `()`
  |                    in this macro invocation
  |
  = note: required by `std::ops::Carrier::from_error`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `(): std::ops::Carrier` is not satisfied
 --> <anon>:6:5
  |
6 |     file.read_to_string(&mut contents)?;
  |     -----------------------------------
  |     |
  |     the trait `std::ops::Carrier` is not implemented for `()`
  |     in this macro invocation
  |
  = note: required by `std::ops::Carrier::from_error`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Comment: I upvoted. IMO, this is not a stupid question, since the `?` operator is a little cryptic, and it is counter intuitive that the code example cannot be put in a `main`. If I well remember, there is a RFC for permitting to use `Result` in a main.

Comment: For me the error log is confuse so upvote too.

Comment: Relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43395610/1233251

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`?` is a syntactic sugar that checks a `Result`: if the result is `Err`, it is returned *as if*. If there is no error (aka `Ok`), the function continue. When you type this:

```
fn main() {
    use std::fs::File;

    let _ = File::open("foo.txt")?;
}
```

that means:

```
fn main() {
    use std::fs::File;

    let _ = match File::open("foo.txt") {
        Err(e)  => return Err(e),
        Ok(val) => val,
    };
}
```

Then you understand that for now, you cannot use `?` in the main, because main returns unit `()` and not `Result`. If you want this stuff to work, you can put it in a function that returns a `Result` and check it from main:

```
fn my_stuff() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    use std::fs::File;
    use std::io::prelude::*;

    let mut file = File::open("foo.txt")?;
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents)?;
    // do whatever you want with `contents`
    Ok(())
}


fn main() {
    if let Err(_) = my_stuff() {
        // manage your error
    }
}
```

PS: There is a [proposition](http://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1937) to make work `?` in the main.

Answer (score 4):

They *do* compile.  They just don't compile in a `main` function like that.  If you look at the examples, they all have a big "Run" button on them.  Click that and it opens the full, unabridged example on the playpen.

The one you've used above expands to this code:

```
fn main() {
    use std::fs::File;
    use std::io::prelude::*;

    fn foo() -> std::io::Result<()> {
        let mut file = File::open("foo.txt")?;
        let mut contents = String::new();
        file.read_to_string(&mut contents)?;
        assert_eq!(contents, "Hello, world!");
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

That code doesn't compile because you've put code that propagates a `Result` into a function (`main` in this case) that doesn't return a `Result`.

Comment: I saw the run button and noted the code was different. My first thought was that one or other versions was out-of-date. I suspected also that it had something to do with the `?` but being brand new to rust I did not know what `?` did.