# How to convert a Rust char to an integer so that '1' becomes 1?

Tags: rust

I am trying to find the sum of the digits of a given number. For example, `134` will give `8`.

My plan is to convert the number into a string using `.to_string()` and then use `.chars()` to iterate over the digits as characters. Then I want to convert every `char` in the iteration into an integer and add it to a variable. I want to get the final value of this variable.

I tried using the code below to convert a `char` into an integer:

```
fn main() {
    let x = "123";
    for y in x.chars() {
        let z = y.parse::<i32>().unwrap();
        println!("{}", z + 1);
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=132027c6a92b20e5d39298ff2d3bdc24&version=stable&backtrace=0))

But it results in this error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `parse` found for type `char` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:4:19
  |
4 |         let z = y.parse::<i32>().unwrap();
  |                   ^^^^^
```

This code does exactly what I want to do, but first I have to convert each `char` into a string and then into an integer to then increment `sum` by `z`.

```
fn main() {
    let mut sum = 0;
    let x = 123;
    let x = x.to_string();
    for y in x.chars() {
        // converting `y` to string and then to integer
        let z = (y.to_string()).parse::<i32>().unwrap();
        // incrementing `sum` by `z`
        sum += z;
    }
    println!("{}", sum);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8aae5aac5ead131f58633609f272a981&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Comment: It gives me `binary operation + cannot be applied to type char`

when I try to add something to it

Comment: If you want to parse the whole integer, all you need is `let v: i32 = x.parse()?;`. Can you check whether this is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043268/convert-a-string-to-int-in-rust ?

Comment: Sorry, that may have been confusing. It's an integral value, but it's a separate type because it's not a type you are supposed to do arithmetic on. My question stands: what output do you expect from your program?

Comment: @Ritiek: No problem; I also have the same problem when asking a question that the context seems obvious to me since I've been working on it for some time :)

Comment: @shepmaster: Isn't the `+1`confusing as the code would print `2,3,4` (if it would compile).

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek perhaps, but it's *what the OP tried*. Presumably they added that to demonstrate that they wanted the ability to use addition on the result, but that's just guessing on my part.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The method you need is [`char::to_digit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.to_digit). It converts `char` to a number it represents in the given radix.

You can also use [`Iterator::sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum) to calculate sum of a sequence conveniently:

```
fn main() {
    const RADIX: u32 = 10;
    let x = "134";
    println!("{}", x.chars().map(|c| c.to_digit(RADIX).unwrap()).sum::<u32>());
}
```

Comment: `flat_map` may be used if you don't care about the failure to convert.

Comment: @AurevoirXavier nope I did not mean that.

Comment: @Shepmaster do you mean like `x.chars().flat_map(|x| c.to_digit(RADIX))`? Is this because flattening a result will either panic or give the value?

Comment: @aravk33, [`filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) is a good fit here since it will uwrap `Option<u32>`: `x.chars().filter_map(|c| c.to_digit(RADIX))`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @murlakatamenka No, I mean `flat_map`. See [Why does `Option` support `IntoIterator`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43285372/155423)

Comment: @aravk33 no it does not panic. See [Why does `Option` support `IntoIterator`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43285372/155423)

Answer (score 21):

```
my_char as u32 - '0' as u32
```

Now, there's a lot more to unpack about this answer.

It works because the ASCII (and thus UTF-8) encodings have the Arabic numerals 0-9 ordered in ascending order. You can get the scalar values and subtract them.

However, what should it do for values *outside* this range? What happens if you provide `'p'`? It returns 64. What about `'.'`? This will panic. And `'♥'` will return 9781.

**Strings are not just bags of bytes**. They are UTF-8 encoded and you cannot just ignore that fact. Every `char` can hold any Unicode scalar value.

That's why strings are the wrong abstraction for the problem.

From an efficiency perspective, allocating a string seems inefficient. [Rosetta Code has an example of using an iterator](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sum_digits_of_an_integer#Rust) which only does numeric operations:

```
struct DigitIter(usize, usize);

impl Iterator for DigitIter {
    type Item = usize;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.0 == 0 {
            None
        } else {
            let ret = self.0 % self.1;
            self.0 /= self.1;
            Some(ret)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", DigitIter(1234, 10).sum::<usize>());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If `c` is your character you can just write:

```rs
c as i32 - 0x30;
```

Test with:

```rs
let c:char = '2';
let n:i32 = c as i32 - 0x30;
println!("{}", n);
```

output:

```
2
```

*NB: 0x30 is '0' in ASCII table, easy enough to remember!*

Comment: Why not use '0' as i32?

Comment: I used to hack roms so I took the habit of translating the hexa into the corresponding value. I think that 0x30-0x39 corresponding to 0-9 works on pretty much any OS and it is easy to remember

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to iterate over the characters of your string and convert and add them using `fold`.

```
fn sum_of_string(s: &str) -> u32 {
  s.chars().fold(0, |acc, c| c.to_digit(10).unwrap_or(0) + acc)
}

fn main() {
    let x = "123";
    println!("{}", sum_of_string(x));
}
```