# Is there a builtin identity function in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a vector of `Option`s and I want to filter only the `Some`s. I use `filter_map` with identity:

```
let v = vec![Some(1), None, Some(2)];
for i in v.into_iter().filter_map(|o| o) {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

Is there a builtin function permitting to write something like `filter_map(identity)`?

Comment: Note that `identity` is 4 more characters than your original example; I'd expect people would be too lazy to type it out ^_^.

Comment: @Shepmaster Sometime expressivity is better than brevity :p

Comment: @Shepmaster : As with your answer, F# calls it `id`, so there's precedent for that in the stdlib at least.

Comment: Same with Haskell. [`id`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=id)s everywhere!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is an [`std::convert::identity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/fn.identity.html) function as of [Rust 1.33.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2019/02/28/Rust-1.33.0.html).

Answer (score 13):

## Answering your question

After Rust 1.33, see [the sibling answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52525620/155423).

Before Rust 1.33, there is no such function in stable Rust. You can create your own:

```
fn id<T>(v: T) -> T { v }
```

Although most people just inline the code, as you did.

## Solving your problem

After Rust 1.29, use [`Iterator::flatten`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten):

```
let v = vec![Some(1), None, Some(2)];
for i in v.into_iter().flatten() {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

Before Rust 1.29, use [`Iterator::flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map):

```
let v = vec![Some(1), None, Some(2)];
for i in v.into_iter().flat_map(|o| o) {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

See also:

- [Why does `Option` support `IntoIterator`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43285372/155423)

Comment: I made another one when the item is not moved: `fn id_deref<T>(v: &Option<T>) -> Option<&T> {v.as_ref()}`

Comment: @Boiethios I'd be very hesitant to call that anything like "identity" considering it changes the value. I'd also not call it "deref" because that means something in Rust which isn't what that function does. Also, that function is redundant; you can just say `Option::as_ref` instead.