# Why does the second call to my FFI function fail to match the string comparison?

Tags: rust, ffi, unsafe

This code shows FFI from Rust to Fortran because it's where I noticed the issue, but I'm pretty sure this is not Fortran specific and maybe even FFI-independent.

I have src/main.rs, a rather minimal thing:

```rust
extern crate libc;

extern "C" {
    static mut __wrapper_mod_MOD_a_string: [libc::c_char; 30];
    fn __wrapper_mod_MOD_say_hi();
}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("hello");
    unsafe { __wrapper_mod_MOD_say_hi() };

    for i in unsafe { __wrapper_mod_MOD_a_string.iter_mut() } {
        *i = ' ' as libc::c_char;
    }

    for (i, c) in unsafe { __wrapper_mod_MOD_a_string }.iter_mut().zip(s.chars()) {
        *i = c as libc::c_char;
    }

    unsafe { __wrapper_mod_MOD_say_hi() };

    for (i, c) in unsafe { __wrapper_mod_MOD_a_string.iter_mut().zip(s.chars()) } {
        *i = c as libc::c_char;
    }

    unsafe { __wrapper_mod_MOD_say_hi() };
}
```

This calls into src/wrapper.f90:

```
module wrapper_mod
   implicit none

   private
   public :: say_hi
   character(30) :: a_string

contains

   subroutine say_hi
      if (trim(a_string) == 'hello') then
         write(6,*) 'Howdy there, partner'
      else
         write(6,*) 'Rude of you not to greet me'
      endif
   end subroutine say_hi
end module wrapper_mod
```

I get the output:

```
 Rude of you not to greet me
 Rude of you not to greet me
 Howdy there, partner
```

**Why?** The only difference in the last two lines is the scoping of the `unsafe` block. I thought the unsafe action is the access over FFI, but once I have an array, it should be "safe" to iterate it as I please. Clearly I've misunderstood something.

My Cargo.toml has `cc = "1.0"` in `[build-dependencies]` and I have the following build.rs:

```
extern crate cc;

fn main() {
    cc::Build::new()
        .file("src/wrapper.f90")
        .compile("libwrapper.a");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=wrapper");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=gfortran");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing particular about the use of `unsafe` here. The same thing happens with regular curly braces:

```
fn main() {
    let mut bytes = [0; 4];
    let new_bytes = b"demo";

    for (i, &c) in { bytes }.iter_mut().zip(new_bytes) {
        *i = c;
    }

    println!("{:?}", bytes);
    // [0, 0, 0, 0]

    for (i, &c) in { bytes.iter_mut().zip(new_bytes) } {
        *i = c;
    }

    println!("{:?}", bytes);
    // [100, 101, 109, 111]
}
```

Usage of the curly braces forces a move of the variables inside the braces. Since `[libc::c_char; 30]` and `[u8; 4]` both implement `Copy`, an implicit copy is made due to move. You can take a mutable reference and move that through the curly braces:

```
for (i, &c) in { &mut bytes }.iter_mut().zip(new_bytes) {
    *i = c;
}
```

See also:

- [What's the difference between &mut unsafe { } and unsafe { &mut }?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61605289/155423)
- [Is there a builtin identity function in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45968885/155423)
- [Cannot obtain a mutable reference when iterating a recursive structure: cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37986640/155423)
- [Stuff the Identity Function Does (in Rust)](https://bluss.github.io/rust/fun/2015/10/11/stuff-the-identity-function-does/)