# What's the difference between &mut unsafe { } and unsafe { &mut }?

Tags: rust

I want to convert `*mut` pointer to `&mut` reference.

```rust
// Both setting a value to ptr and getting a value from ptr succeeds.
let ptr: &mut usize = unsafe { &mut *(VIRTUAL_ADDRESS_TO_ACCESS_FREE_PAGE as *mut usize) };
```

This works. However, if `&mut` is outside of `unsafe` block, the code will not work partially. `*ptr = foo` will not store `foo` to the memory `ptr` points, but `let foo = *ptr` will assign the value of `*ptr` to `foo`.

```rust
// Setting a value to ptr fails, but getting a value from ptr succeeds.
let ptr: &mut usize = &mut unsafe { *(VIRTUAL_ADDRESS_TO_ACCESS_FREE_PAGE as *mut usize) };
```

What's the difference between `unsafe { &mut }` and `&mut unsafe{ }`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with `unsafe` per-se, rather with *block boundaries*.

`&*ptr` is a "reborrow", it's just going to reinterpret the pointer to a new form. So you get different types of pointers (one raw and one reference) to the same object.

`&{*ptr}` is completely different, because `{*ptr}` will [force a copy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/block-expr.html)<sup>[0]</sup> (thanks @harmic for the sourcing):

> Blocks are always value expressions and evaluate the last expression in value expression context. This can be used to force moving a value if really needed.

Then it will borrow that copy. This means you get two pointers *to completely different objects*.

The objects have the same value since one's pointee is a copy of the other's, and thus *reading* seems to work, but *writing* doesn't because... you're not writing where you think you are.

See [this demonstration](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=38eaf16e9e661b8dc4d380c2799e9600) (not using mut pointers because there's no need to to demonstrate the issue)

---

<sup>[0]</sup> more generally a move but here you're pointing to a `usize` which is Copy

Comment: Might be worth adding a link to [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/block-expr.html) where it says: "Blocks are always value expressions and evaluate the last expression in value expression context. This can be used to force moving a value if really needed."