# Why does `a` keeps the ownership after `let b = &*&a;` in Rust?

Tags: rust, ownership

I found it confusing that `&(*&a)` and `&{*&a}` behave differently.

To be detailed, the following code failed to compile:

```rust
struct CanNotCopy;
fn main(){
    let a = CanNotCopy;
    &{*&a};
    let c = a;
}
```

And the following code compiled:

```rust
struct CanNotCopy;
fn main(){
    let a = CanNotCopy;
    &(*&a); // or &*&a;
    let c = a;
}
```

What is the semantical difference between the above codes?

Which are language constructs that lead to the transfer of ownership, precisely?

Comment: `()` and `{}` are different themselves, the first just modifies the order of operations, while the second creates a new nested scope.

Comment: @Netwave thanks for your comment. I know `()` and `{}` are conceptually different, but a more precise description (e.g. a list of language constructs that transfer the ownership) will make things more clear. I am sorry that I have tried and did not found such materials existing on the Internet. The language reference definitely describe such stuff but it is too hard for a beginner to read the language reference.

Comment: [Block Expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/block-expr.html), last paragraph (before the last code snippet).

Comment: [Stuff the Identity Function Does (in Rust)](https://bluss.github.io/rust/fun/2015/10/11/stuff-the-identity-function-does/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using `{}` you are **moving** `a` into a new scope, which then you play referencing and dereferencing. It can also be simplified to:

```rust
struct CanNotCopy;
fn main(){
    let a = CanNotCopy;
    {a};
    let c = a;
}
```

You would be getting the same problem, now lets move to the other problem. Imagine you have a reference before the scope:

```rust
struct CanNotCopy;
fn main(){
    let a = CanNotCopy;
    let aa = &a;
    {aa};
    let c = a;
}
```

This works, because we just move the reference and not the original object itself.

How about the operations with `*` and `&` then:

```rust
struct CanNotCopy;
fn main(){
    let a = CanNotCopy;
    let aa = &a;
    &{*aa};
    let c = a;
}
```

We got to a `cannot move out of *aa which is behind a shared reference` because of the same reasons above showed.

We do not have that error with `()` because we are working within the same scope hence nothing is really moving there.

EDIT (taken from comments), Some related questions:

- [What does “&*” do in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807445/what-does-do-in-rust)
- [What's the difference between &mut unsafe { } and unsafe { &mut }?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61605289/whats-the-difference-between-mut-unsafe-and-unsafe-mut)

Comment: Thanks for @Netwave 's answer. The following links might be helpful for people with similary confusion with me: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807445/what-does-do-in-rust; 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61605289/whats-the-difference-between-mut-unsafe-and-unsafe-mut