# Why can I not get a specific field from a Result of a Vec of a structure?

Tags: rust

I have a structure and a function call:

```rust
pub fn get_exchanges(database: &str) -> Result<Vec<Exchanges>> {
    todo!()
}

pub struct Exchanges {
    pub rowid: u64,
    pub table_name: String,
    pub profile_id: String,
    pub name: String,
    pub etl_type: i16,
    pub connection_info: String,
    pub update_flag: bool,
    pub date_last_update: String,
    pub gui_show: bool,
    pub reports_flag: bool,
}
```

I want to pull out the name within the structure and do some work on it.  I have an iterator but cannot figure out how to get to the specific item called `name`.

```rust
let exchanges_list = get_exchanges("crypto.db");
for name in exchanges_list {
    println!("exchange {:?}", name);
    //ui.horizontal(|ui| ui.label(exchange));
}
```

The result is

```
 Exchanges { rowid: 4, table_name: "exchanges", profile_id: "None", name: "coinbasepro_noFlag", etl_type: 2, connection_info: "{\"name\":\"coinbase_pro\",\"base_url\":\"https://api.pro.coinbase.com\",\"key\":\"[redacted]\",\"secret\":\"[redacted]\",\"passphrase\":\"[redacted]\"}", update_flag: false, date_last_update: "2009-01-02 00:00:00 UTC", gui_show: true, reports_flag: true }
```

Comment: I’d suggest you might want to remove the secret, passphrase, and key info if those are as confidential as their names sound, since this is a public site that probably gets trawled for such things.

Comment: I have removed them and requested a moderator expunge from the history. OP, you should still immediately invalidate those credentials and request new ones. The Internet never forgets...

Comment: [Why does `Option` support `IntoIterator`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43285372/155423)

Answer (score 1):

`get_exchanges` returns a `Result`, which represents either success or failure.  This type implements `IntoIterator` and is therefore a valid value to be iterated in a `for` loop, but in this case that's just iterating over the single `Vec` value. If you want to iterate the `Vec` itself then you need to unwrap the `Result`.  The standard way to do this is using the `?` operator, which will propagate any error out of your function and unwrap the `Result` into the contained value:

```
let exchanges_list = get_exchanges("crypto.db")?;
//                           Add this operator ^
```

If your function does not return a compatible `Result` type, you can instead use `get_exchanges("crypto.db").unwrap()`, which will panic and crash the whole program at runtime if the `Result` represents a failure.  This may be an acceptable alternative if your program doesn't have anything useful to do when encountering an error at this point.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to call `.unwrap()` since the value is a `Result`; that’ll let you use the `Vec` inside. Then, you can iterate with `.iter()` if you want to get the names:

```
let exch_lst = get_exchanges("crypto.db").unwrap();
for exch in exch_lst.iter() {
    println(“exchange: {}”, exch.name.as_str());
}
```

There are other methods besides `for + iter`; this is just the one that seemed to fit best with what you already had.